# How to display success and error messages after postback?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I am using ASP.NET and C#.

I have a form in which the user can upload a file to the server.  It does a client-side validation check with Javascript to make sure it is the correct file type, etc.  If it passes that, control is handed off to the `aspx.cs` codebehind file.  After the upload happens, I want to display a success notification on the same page or an error notification if any error is thrown.

How do I create a variable that can be passed back to the `aspx` file and displayed?

**upload.aspx**

```
<html>
<%@ Page Language="C#" CodeFile="upload.aspx.cs" Inherits="Upload" %>
...
<head>
<script language="Javascript">
    function validate()
    {
        var filter = /<stuff>/;

        var file1 = document.getElementById("uploadfile1").value;
        var file2 = document.getElementById("uploadfile2").value;
        var file3 = document.getElementById("uploadfile3").value;

        //validation code to make sure uploaded file is legit
        if (success)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            alert("File not legit. Please correct.");
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
</head>

<body>

    //I want to put something here like:
    //<% if success is given, display "Successful Upload" in green %>
    //<% if failure is given, display "Error Uploading" in red %>

    <form method="post" runat="server" action="upload.aspx" name="upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <asp:FileUpload ID="uploadfile1" runat="server" />
        <asp:FileUpload ID="uploadfile2" runat="server" />
        <asp:FileUpload ID="uploadfile3" runat="server" />

        <asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" Text="Upload" onClientClick="return validate()" onClick="btnUpload_Click" />
    </form>

</body>


</html>
```

**upload.aspx.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class Upload_File : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FileUpload[] files = new FileUpload[3];
        files[0] = uploadfile1;
        files[1] = uploadfile2;
        files[2] = uploadfile3;

        string rootpath = "C:\\path\\to\\directory\\";

        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            if(files[i].HasFile)
            {
                files[i].SaveAs(rootpath + files[i].FileName);

                //I want to put something here like: 
                //var uploadTime = getTimeStamp();
                //var VariableToPass = "Files uploaded at " + uploadTime;
                //also, a way to catch error thrown and set success/error boolean
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for a popup alert or something else?

Comment: No, I am looking for messages to be displayed on the page itself in red or green text after server side is finished processing.

Comment: Add an `asp:Label` and set the text and color in the code behind.  What's the problem?

Comment: are you familiar with validation controls ..? also have you looked at any FileUpload Controls or considered `Ajax tool Kit` if you are using Javascript Alert() why not use that as well to show a message that the upload has been successful... think outside the box a little here `noblerare` also since buttons trigger `Postbacks` why can't you capture that in a session or static variable and in one of the Events `Page_Load, or Pre_Render` change the color of the label to the appropriate color..?

Comment: Thank you `DJ KRAZE`.  I will look into the technologies you mentioned.  I am new to C# and ASP.NET so I am bumbling my way around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.saveas%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

This link has the upload success message.

`<asp:Label id="UploadStatusLabel"
            runat="server">
        </asp:Label>`

if successful use `UploadStatusLabel.Forecolor = green`

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I think I should be good to go from the path that both you and `DJ Kraze` pointed me on.